# Int64 as result from double times 10^x?

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I have a variable representing a quantity in some given unit:

```
enum Unit
{
  Single,
  Thousand,
  Million,
  Billion,
  Trillion
}

public class Quantity()
{

  public double number;
  public Unit numberUnit;

  public Int64 GetNumberInSingleUnits()
  {
    // ???
  }

}
```

For example, imagine

```
var GDP_Of_America = new Quantiy { number = 16.66, numberUnit = Unit.Trillion };
Int64 gdp = GDP_Of_America.GetNumberinSingleUnits();  // should return 16,660,000,000,000
```

My question is basically - how can I implement the "GetNumberInSingleUnits" function?
I can't just multiply with some UInt64 factor, e.g.

```
        double num = 0.5;
        UInt64 factor = 1000000000000;

        var result = num * factor; // won't work! results in double
```

As the regular numeric operations reslt in a double, but the result may be larger than the range of valid doubles.

How could I do this conversion?

ps, I know the class "Quantity" is not a great way to store information - but this is bound by the input data of my application, which is in non-single (e.g. millions, billions etc) units.

Comment: Are you sure an `Int64` can hold a higher number than a `double` can?

Comment: Now I'm entirely confused. It seems true that Double.MinValue <= Int64.MinValue and Double.MaxValue >= Int64.MaxValue. How is that even possible? Both are 8 byte types.

Comment: Too late for edit, but: Alright, seems like its a matter of accuracy, with double only being 100% accurate til 2^54 - which does mean that Int64 would most likely still be the better option for me

Comment: You can cast your `result` to `long`: `return (long)result;`. That will lose precision, but oh well. Or use `decimal` types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I said, `decimal`s can help you here:

```
public enum Unit
{
    Micro = -6, Milli = -3, Centi = -2, Deci = -1,
    One /* Don't really like this name */, Deca, Hecto, Kilo, Mega = 6, Giga = 9
}

public struct Quantity
{
    public decimal Value { get; private set; }

    public Unit Unit { get; private set; }

    public Quantity(decimal value, Unit unit) : 
        this()
    {
        Value = value;
        Unit = unit;
    }

    public decimal OneValue /* This one either */
    {
        get
        {
            return Value * (decimal)Math.Pow(10, (int)Unit);
        }
    }
}
```

With `decimal`s you won't lose a lot of precision until after you decide to convert them to `long` (and beware of over/underflows).

Comment: Thanks Anton, great input. Have to see if I face any imprecisions that way, but first tests look pretty good. I've thought of a second way, will post below - but will mark yours as answer as it looks much cleaner.

Comment: The `Math.Pow(10, (int)Unit)` doesn't play well with the `Mega` and `Giga`, as their gap is bigger than 10 times

Comment: @grek40 Whoops, my bad. Don't know what was I thinking. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Anton's answer seems like a good solution.
Just for the sake of discussion, another potential way.

I don't like this one at all as it seems very messy; However I think this *might* avoid imprecisions, if these ever turned out to be an issue with decimals.

```
public Int64 GetAsInt64(double number)
{
    // Returns 1 for single units, 3 for thousands, 6 for millions, etc.
    uint e = GetFactorExponent();

    // Converts to scientific notation
    // e.g. number = -1.2345, unit millions to "-1.2345e6"
    string str = String.Format("{0:#,0.###########################}", number) + "e" + e;

    // Parses scientific notation into Int64
    Int64 result = Int64.Parse(str, NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowExponent | NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
    return result;
}
```